# jQuery how often do resize window scripts execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know on the face of it this sounds like a daft question, but I build a lot of responsive sites, and as such run a lot of my scripts inside a window resize function for when tablets etc are turned from landscape to portrait.

My question is really what are the increments in which the scripts register a window resize, is it on a pixel by pixel basis for example?

I'm currently wanting to rebuild a lot of my scripts to be separated into width range event listeners to hopefully speed up the scripts. As an example this script beneath, lets say at certain points i want a div to change widths,

```
function resizeFrame() {
  var wWidth = $(window).width()
  if ((100 < wWidth) && (wWidth < 500)){
    $('.sample').width(300);
  }
  else if ((500 <= wWidth) && (wWidth < 900)){
    $('.sample').width(700);
    }
  else{
    $('.sample').width(900);
  }
};

jQuery(function($){
  $(window).resize(resizeFrame);
});
```

During window resizes does the div get given a width once when it satisfies a condition, or during resize is the div being resized to the same value at every increment?

**EDIT**

This script is an example to help outline my question, there are easier ways to achieve this i know.

Comment: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

Comment: BTW, any reason to not use CSS3 media queries?

Comment: why are u not using @media query in css ??.. whats d the need of resizing a div

Comment: @A.Wolff in this example script then yes, CSS3 media queries would be the way forward, the actual scripts I use are much more complex, this was just for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: @TimWilkinson Then it makes sense, anyway, you should check for matchMedia instead, see e.g: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia  **<||>** https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/   **<||>** http://caniuse.com/matchmedia

Comment: We use a timeout to stop the trigger of resize when the resize is coming in too fast. Basically the resize only triggers when an average user is done resizing the window.

Comment: The problem with the timeout is that it induces a percievable lag to the update which in my opinion does not do justice to the user experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**START EDIT** Currently during resize your div is being resized to the same value at every increment. To answer the question, the resize event is triggered very frequently - too fast to perform much processing / DOM manipulation each time. (See below for my suggestion for reducing the number of executions of the code inside the consitions.) **END EDIT**

It seems you conditions are not correct to get the desired effect (code executed only once when changing into a different width range). Maybe you should try taking into account the current div width:

```
function resizeFrame() {
  var wWidth = $(window).width()
  var currentWidth = $('.sample').width();

    // for debug
   var updated = false;


  if ((currentWidth != 300) && (wWidth >= 100) && (wWidth < 500)){
    $('.sample').width(300);
      updated = true;
  }
  else if ( (currentWidth != 700) && (wWidth >= 500) && (wWidth < 900)){
    $('.sample').width(700);
      updated = true;
  }
  else if (currentWidth != 900 && wWidth >= 900) {
    $('.sample').width(900);
      updated = true;
  }

     // for debug
    $('.sample').html("window:" + wWidth + " div:" +  currentWidth + " updated: " + updated);
};

jQuery(function($){
  $(window).resize(resizeFrame);
});
```

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4SpN/4/)

Comment: my script seems to work fine at this end? what browser were you testing it on? and thanks for the input but as previously stated the question wasn't regarding the script itself, it is to back up a more general questions about how jQuery handles resize queries.

Comment: It seems from your question that the concern of the exercise is performance related. So when you resize window width from 200 to 201, to 202... your code inside the 1st condition is being executed each time! Is this really necessary??

Comment: well yea thats what my question is, i am inclined to beleive it is not necessary, and some comments and answers above give good ways to improve performance...

Comment: Whether it is necesary or not depends on exactly what you are doing on the resize event... What exactly are you doing by the way?? :)

Comment: this was where i struggled to ask the question accurately as depending on the site depends on what scripts i run, hence the bad example as a guide lol. One one site i clone an entire menu below a certain size, others affect layout, what images to load, the list goes on, hence looking for general ideas about how to achieve improved performance across the board.

Answer (score 0):

How often it triggers is, by my best guess, depending on the machine you're running the script on. If the machine is fast then it will be triggered more often than when the machine is slow. But never the less, it will execute the same amount of times.

http://jsfiddle.net/YA426/

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    console.log("Resize")
})
```

If you run my example and resize the inner windows, it will trigger by a pixel-by-pixel resizing. If you resize your browser window it will trigger less, but in a chunk in the end.

My answer is purely based on the example, so I could very well be wrong :)